# Reading and writing column data in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

This endeavour is a variation on the wonderful [Mac Model Shelf](https://github.com/MagerValp/MacModelShelf). I have managed thus far to write the code myself that can read single Mac serial numbers at the command line and give back the corresponding model type, based on on the last 3 or 4 chars in the serial.

Write now I am trying to write a script to read-in the column data in an Excel file and return back the results for each cell in the neighbouring column.

The output Excel would hopefully looking something like this (with headers)...

```
Serial         Model
C12PT70EG8WP   Macbook Pro 2015 15" 2.5 Ghz i7
K12PT7EG0PW    iMac 2010 Intel Core Duo 1.6 Ghz
```

This is all based on excel file that supplies its data to a python shelve. Here is a small example of how it reads... I've called it 'pgList.xlsx' in the main code. In reality it will be hundreds of lines long.

```
G8WP   Macbook Pro 2015 15" 2.5 Ghz i7
0PW    iMac 2010 Intel Core Duo 1.6 Ghz
3RT    iPad Pro 2017
```

Main python3 code...

```
import shelve
import pandas as pd

#getting the shelve/database ready from the library excel file
DBPATH = "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/shelve/macmodelshelfNEW"
databaseOfMacs = shelve.open(DBPATH) 
excelDict = pd.read_excel('pgList.xlsx', header=None, index_col=0,squeeze=True).to_dict()
databaseOfMacs.update(excelDict)

#loading up the excel file and serial numbers I want to examine...
df = pd.read_excel('testSerials.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
listSerials = df['Serial']
listModels = df['Model']

for i in listSerials:
    inputSerial = i
    inputSerial = inputSerial.upper()

    modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial = ""   

    if len(inputSerial) == 12:
        modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial = inputSerial[-4:]
    elif len(inputSerial) == 11:
        modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial = inputSerial[-3:]


    try:
        model = databaseOfMacs[modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial]
        #printing to console to check code works
        print(model)

    except:
        print("Result not found")

databaseOfMacs.clear()
databaseOfMacs.close()
```

Could you guys help me out with writing of the results back to the same excel file? So example, if the serial number was in cell A2, the result (the model type) would be written to B2?

I have tried including this line of code before the main 'for' loop in the code but it only ever serves to wipe the Excel file empty after running the script! I just comment it out for the moment.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testSerials.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Could you also help me handle any potential blank cells in the serials column? 
A blank will throw back this error.

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

Thanks again for looking after me!

WL

**UPDATE**

The comments I have up to now have really helped. I think the part where am I getting stuck at is getting the output of the 'for' loop, 'model' in this case into the column for 'Models. The variable 'listModels' doesn't seem to behave like other lists in Python 3 i.e I cannot append anything to it.

**UPDATE 2**

Some more tinkering, trying to get the result of the serial-number lookup of the values in "Serial" column into the "Model" column.

I have tried (without any real success)

```
    try:

        model = databaseOfMacs[modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial]

        print(model)

        listModels.replace(['nan'], [model], inplace=True)
```

This doesn't give me an error message but still nothing appears in the outputted excel file.

When I run a for loop to print the contents of 'listModels' I just back a list of "NaN"s, suggesting nothing at all has been changed... bummer!

I've also tried

```
try:

    model = databaseOfMacs[modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial]

    print(model)

    listModels[i] = model
```

This will spit back a console error about

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

but at least I can see the modelname relating to a serial number in the console when I iterate through 'listModels', still nothing in the output Excel file though (along with a 'nan' for every serial number that is examined?)

I am sure it's something small that I am missing in the code to fix this problem. Thanks again to anybody who can help me out.

**UPDATE 3**

I've solved it on my own. Just had to use a while loop instead.

```
sizeOfSerialsList = len(listSerials)

count = 0


while (count < sizeOfSerialsList):
    inputSerial = listSerials.iloc[count]
    inputSerial = str(inputSerial).upper()
    modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial = ""
    model = ""


    if len(inputSerial) == 12:
        modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial = inputSerial[-4:]
    elif len(inputSerial) == 11:
        modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial = inputSerial[-3:]

    try:
        model = databaseOfMacs[modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial]
        listModels.iloc[count] = model
    except:
        listModels.iloc[count] = "Not found"

    count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Update 3 for code that solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

From the [XlsxWriter docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html), you'll need to call `df.to_excel(writer)` followed by `writer.save()`.

To avoid that AttributeError, one fix (maybe not the most python-3-esque?) is to change `inputSerial = inputSerial.upper()` to `inputSerial = str(inputSerial).upper()`.

Comment: The Attribute error problem is now fixed, super. I am not sure where or how to implement the first two lines of code though.